# Not going to view in ASP.NET MVC web application from action and stays on previous view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I'm passing an id from a view named "profile" via javascrpt with this code:

```
function myPage(id)
{
    console.log(id); 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('/Home/send_page', { myID: id },
            function (data, status) { })
    })
    console.log("still here"); 
}
```

which is perfectly working and I'm seeing myID in my action which is this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult send_page(int myID)
{
    TempData["id_"] = myID;
    return RedirectToAction("main");
}
```

and then I'm going into a action named main which has same name of a view, and into "main"

I'm showing content of a viewbag.

Here is main function:

```
    public ActionResult main()
    {
        int myID = Int32.Parse(TempData["id_"].ToString());
        var sth = (from x in db.essays where (x.e_id == myID) select x).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.title = sth.title;
        ViewBag.context = sth.context;

        return View();
    }
```

and I built the main view using AddView.

Now, anytime that I click to pass id (which works and id is passed) view doesn't change and it stays in "profile" view not in "main" view. and what something has is fine two and it revoked perfectly.

But still it stays in profile.

I've tested this kind of redirecting still not working:

```
return View("~/Views/Home/main.cshtml");
```

There's a pending add (green +) beside of main view.

Comment: While with ajax post, if you check the Browser (F12) Debugger console, the response was returned as a View. If you want to redirect the page when response succeeded, you need `window.location.href = /* Url to redirect */;`.

Comment: why when i'm doing it via action in controller it doesn't change?